# JavaScript - Reading from dropdown box

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I need to be able to read from a dropdown box on a page get the value from it and thats it (for now) I currently have this code.

JavaScript

```
function main(input)
{
    value = getValue();
    alert(value);
}

function getValue()
{
    var len = document.form1.values.length
    var chosen = ""

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (document.form1.values[i].selected) {
            chosen = document.form1.values[i].value
        } 
    }

return chosen;
}
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Shopping Cart</title>
        <link href="style.css" title="Style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="javascript/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <!-- Start content -->
    <body>
        <!-- Wrapper to hold all content in -->
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Top header, site name, moto, all that -->
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Kyle's Legit Toys</h1>
                <h2>We are more legit then 10th.exe</h2>
                <h3>#SoundsLegit</h3>
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation Menu -->
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/ks339/sem2/clientValidation.htm">Client Validation</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="first">
                <p>Wickedy Walker</p>
                <img src="i/car.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Car" title="#CoolCar">
                <p>Cost: £30 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <p>Faster than light car</p>
                <img src="i/toycar.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="ToyCar" title="#WickCar">
                <p>Cost: £10 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <p>Build stuff crane</p>
                <img src="i/crane.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Toy Crane" title="#SweetCrane">
                <p>Cost: £15 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Dynamicaly altered payment -->
            <div id="payment">
                <p>Payment</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

            <!-- Clear all floats -->
            <div class="clear">
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="first">
                <p>Satch Boogie</p>
                <img src="i/guitar.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Guitar" title="#BeLikeSlash">
                <p>Cost: £20 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <p>HaxTop</p>
                <img src="i/laptop.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Laptop" title="#Be1337hax">
                <p>Cost: £150 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <p>Train</p>
                <img src="i/train.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Train" title="#ChoChoTrain">
                <p>Cost: £5 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Clear all floats -->
            <div class="clear">
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="first">
                <p>Pedo Bear</p>
                <img src="i/teddybear.gif" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Teddy Bear" title="#AwesomeTeddy">
                <p>Cost: £5 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <p>Not a pony bear</p>
                <img src="i/bear.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Teddy Bear" title="#EnvyOfHomies">
                <p>Cost: £5 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <p>Patobo Bear</p>
                <img src="i/irl.jpg" width="85%" height="85%" alt="Teddy Bear" title="#NotEvenRacist">
                <p>Cost: £5 per item</p>

                <form name="form1" method="POST">
                    <select name="values" onchange="main()" >
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Clear all floats -->
            <div class="clear">
            </div>

            <!-- Final footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                <p>Kyle Strudwick - ks339 - StudentNumber</p>
                <p>Some copyright stuff</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error in chrome

[image: The error I get in chrome]

Firebug
[image: Firebug]
[image: Firebug]

Thanks a lot, when answering please try and explain what I did wrong, why it was wrong and the correct way.

Thanks

Comment: +1 perfect question - included ALL code and demonstrated debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your HTML to this :

```
<select name="values" onchange="main(this)" >
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
</select>
```

and you function to this :

```
function main(input)
{
    var text = input.options[input.selectedIndex].text; // returns the text ie one / two etc
    var value = input.value; // returns the value ie 1 / 2 / 3 etc
}
```

**What i have changed** - I have updated the `onchange` from `main()` to `main(this)` this change means thats its passing the current `select` list object to the `main` funciton -  this makes accessing the actual `select` list changing from the function a lot easier - you dont have to go searching the DOM for the select list that changed.

**What does the javascript do** - this simplifies the process of getting the selected option, now we are passed the actual `select` list that has changed ie `input` = the correct select list. We can use `input.selectedIndex` to get the currently selected option and `input.value` to return the currently selected value

Using `document.forms1` wasnt working becuase you have multiple forms with the name `form1` on your page - using `document.forms1[#]` where `#` is the index of the form would work but its confusing ...

**Further changes** - you could remove all but one of the forms if you are using it exactly as you have in your question - as they really are doing nothing ... just surround the entire page (just the content) with a single form - using the above method to get the changed value will still work as it doesn't rely on the form !

[Here is a quick example of the above working](http://jsfiddle.net/zgPQa/)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Good explanation nice a simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

All your forms have the name *form1* so `document.form1` actually returns an array of `<form>` elements. You can access them individually, for example `document.form1[0].values` for the first form. To maintain a generic function you need to pass the current *select* element (the one that the `onchange` event is fired from) into the function so that your function finds the correct *form1* to operate on.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however as you said on his post it's good. Thanks again tho